# Adding java swing combobox to javafx application

Tags: swing, javafx, scenebuilder

I am trying to create a javafx application witch contains just a tab pane and javafx combo box, this is my fxml which I created by scene builder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tab?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TabPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="288.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <TabPane layoutX="-2.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="288.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
        <tabs>
          <Tab text="tab1">
            <content>
              <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                     <children>
                        <ComboBox layoutX="32.0" layoutY="39.0" prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="86.0" />
                     </children>
                  </AnchorPane>
            </content>
          </Tab>
        </tabs>
      </TabPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and this is my simple Main just for call fxml

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TableColumn;
import javafx.scene.control.TableView;
import javafx.scene.control.cell.PropertyValueFactory;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * @author asus
 */
public class Main extends Application{

        @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        
       Scene scene= new Scene(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/javaapplication3/test.fxml")));
        
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setX(0);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(); 
    }
    

}
```

I am looking for a way to use swing combobox which integrated with my fxml file and my application How can I do it, is there any way to use swing component in scene builder of fxml?

Comment: Why would you want to use a swing combo box in a JavaFX application? You would have to manage all kinds of threading issues to do that, as well as wrapping the Swing content in a `SwingNode`, etc. This seems like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: actually I know what you say ,but i have to do , in my linux that i run my application (in situation witch i killall metacity  javafx combo does not work properly it hides when i move mouse , but in a swing simple app with swing combo box it is ok without peoblem),thanks to @James_D